# edit variable of parent batch file from secondary batch file

Tags: batch-file

`a.bat` is parent batch file
`b.bat` is secondary batch file which is started by `a.bat` like this:

```
start b.bat
```

If I "start b.bat" from a batch file a.bat, b.bat can access all variables defined in a.bat, but it can't edit the variables of a.bat.Is there any way so b.bat can edit a variable defined in a.bat...i s this possible with batch scripts?

Comment: try with `call b.bat`

Comment: hi npocmaka, I cant use "call", I need to "start" the second batch due to some reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start` starts a new context (derived from the current one). Any changes (to variables) will be lost, when the started process is finished. Use `call b.bat` to stay in the same context. (unless you use `setlocal` in b.bat)

Comment: ok I get it. So it's not possible with batch. I cant use call, I need to start many such processes and can't wait for b.bat to wait for a single 'call'  to complete to proceed to next call with a different argument

Comment: There is no inter-process communication in batch. You *could* use a temporary file for data exchange.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, ya that's the only way I can see now. Only thing to mention more is that I should use "type" command in a for loop in a.bat to monitor the variable set by b.bat as directly accessing the temp file might give an access denied error in a.bat

Comment: you could use `start /wait b.bat`

Comment: thnx, that helps me simplify things